# Thymeleaf: how to custom tag each children element

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, spring-thymeleaf

I want to render content wrapped by custom tag in a loop, similar to the effect achieved with the th:each attribute."

Fisrt I have a custom tag

```html
<my:categoty loop=5>
    <p>title</p>
<mycategory>
```

I want result

```html
<p>title</p>
<p>title</p>
<p>title</p>
<p>title</p>
<p>title</p>
```

like th:each but i hope not use th:each

I try to get custom tag child tag in AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.class and AbstractElementModelProcessor.class, but I can't found this method

thanks

Comment: Why custom tag? There's already tag exists in JSTL.